# How to parse the following json string into an object?

Tags: javascript, json, object, parsing

```js
var jsonString = '{"DeviceId":3,"results":{"1":"[{\"x\":513,\"y\":565,\"width\":175,\"hight\":208}]"}}';
var message = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

I got an error saying Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse.

Could you please guide me what's wrong?

THanks in advance!

Comment: This is invalid JSON.

Comment: check you json https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: You should check if you missed a part of your object. There are several problems with that string, you have curly brackets crossing the array borders and it seems like the :212 is at the wrong place

Comment: and `hight` should be `height`

Answer (score 0):

At the last few characters looks wrong. The :212 has no sense as the value (that long array) for key "1" was already set, so that later :212 looks weird

Also enclosing it in single quotes it makes that all be like a huge string, and not as an array structure.

Comment: It is in quotes because it is JSON. That is literally in the title of the question

Comment: Yes it does. See the first comments to the question: It needs to be linted. This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: Hey Guys, i edited my json string already, could you please help take a look again?

Answer (score 0):

See Results key as value contains a sub array which contain "1" key which as value contains a string enclosing another json array (but escaped as plain string, so no structurally accesible for the main object . But that string if post -processed the :212 is paired to what? , no key, no comma neighter , to the precedent whole array which already was the value, not the key?. Anyway weird.

Comment: Hi, i edited my json string already, could you please help take a look again?

Answer (score 0):

In your JSON string, there is wrong something with **":212"**, as it's not valid JSON, because it doesn't have any property that it's mapping the value for. For example, you are mapping values for width and height with properties keys. But for "212", there is no property.

Here is the above JSON formatted:

```
var jsonString = '{"DeviceId":"3","results":{"1":"[{\\"x\\":513,\\"y\\":565,\\"width\\":175,\\"hight\\":208}]"}}'
var message = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

If you want to format the results, you can do to it, there is no error on it:

```
JSON.parse(message.results['1'])
```

Here is the JS Bin link for above code: https://jsbin.com/fiyeyet/edit?js,console

Answer (score 0):

Just an advice

Professional code is all about proper spacing, proper identation , proper commenting, don't try to write down all within one single line, structure it VISUALLY nice to see nice to read nice to comprehend, and you will be approved in most jobs.

Hint: declare a normal array/object , convert it to json string using the proper function, then use the string variable returned by the function to test your code or whatever doing. That way, you can write down in the source really nice the structure.